# How to cast MenuItem to LinearLayout

Tags: android, menu, nullpointerexception

I have `NavigationView` with menus.
I am able to get `MenuItem` from `navigationView` by using

```
MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) menuItem;
```

I want to cast `menuItem` to `LinearLayout` or View.

I have set `android:actionViewClass` to `menu` in menu.xml :

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_backup"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sd_card_black_24dp"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.LinearLayout"
    android:title="@string/backup_configuration" />
```

While casting I am facing `NullPointerException`. How can I cast this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this first set custom layout to your `MenuItem` than cast it to `LinearLayout` like below code

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.menu_layout);
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
```

**EDIT**

## [**`setActionView()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat#setactionview) and [**`getActionView()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat#getactionview) method was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.

Direct use **`MenuItem.setActionView()`** and **`MenuItem.getActionView()`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_menu);
        item.setActionView( R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) item.getActionView();
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```