# how to define Android Oncreate optionmenu

Tags: android

When i Override method auto generated bellow this code

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, (android.view.Menu) menu);
        final MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_pending);

        View actionview=MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        mtextcountpending=(Button)actionview.findViewById(R.id.notif_count);
        mtextcountpending.setText("4");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

how to solve Menu menu option menu
error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class there is another class with same `Menu` name and import for that class is already import at top of class. So you getting `android.view.Menu` at your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

Comment: how to solve this problem

Comment: @Tech1stTutorials check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46968012/7666442

Comment: Thanks Mehul Kabaria ,now i changed my Actiivty name Menu to Menuu,,Now perfectly working,,

Comment: Then its appreciate to up vote answer. @Tech1stTutorials